# Why would a change to a label or icon on a dojo IconMenuItem while the page is running not change the page?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When I have the html set up and I run the JS code through a web browser the IconMenuItem never visually changes its icon or label.  Even after JS runs and I call a function on the IconMenuItem, the direct IconMenuItem.label is not empty and the IconMenuItem.icon is "images/icon.png".  How could the element's values be changed but visually in the browser, the IconMenuItem does not change?

Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SwapView" id="MainPageView"
    data-dojo-props="selected:true">

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenu" id="menu"
        style="width: 320px; height: 400px;" data-dojo-props="cols: 3">

        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem" label="empty"
            onclick=handleButton(this) id="btn1"></li>
```

JS:

```
        require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry) {
        var actualButton = registry.byId("btn1");
        actualButton.label=checkbox.title.substring(2);
        actualButton.icon="images/icon.png";
        WL.Logger.debug(actualButton.id+ "'s label is now: " + actualButton.label);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the set method
ex.

```
actualButton.set({label:'newValue',icon:'iconValue'});
```

Check:http://jsfiddle.net/GxGzG/1/

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it had to be something simple